# Validate URLs in jQuery or Javascript before sending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a basic HTML text area which will be used to have URLs pasted into it. Once some URLs are passed into the text area, those will be sent to a server-side script for processing via **AJAX**. I'll be binding those whole process to a `keyUp` event.

The issue is: How will I know I'm sending valid URLs to the script with a client-side check? I don't want to start sending URLs to the PHP script without having them validated in Javascript/jQuery first.

This would be quite easy to solve of the text area accepted one URL only, but the text area needs to accept multiple URLs separated by line breaks. So for example, I'd need to validate this:

```
http://someurl.com/something.ex
https://someurl.com/somethingelse.ext
I-M-NOT-AN-URL
```

So from the above, only the URLs would be sent to the server and `I-M-NOT-AN-URL` would be ignored.

I've not tried anything in regards to this issue since I'm not very familiar with JS, nor found anything as I couldn't come up with a relevant search term I guess, so I'm asking here for help.

Any kind of help on how to tackle this issue would be appreciated.

---

## Update

Based on the comments and answer below, I've come up with the following Javascript/jQuery. I don't know if it efficient, therefore I'm sharing it with you for feedback and help. I don't seem to know how to prepare logic that well in JS... That's lame from my side.

Anyway here I go:

```
    var char_start  = 10;
    var index       = 0;
    var urls        = $('textarea.remote-area');
    var val_ary     = [];
    var urls_ary    = [];
    var single_url  = '';

    urls.keyup(function(){      
        if (urls.val().length >= char_start)
        {           
            var has_lbrs = /\r|\n/i.test(urls.val());
            if (has_lbrs) {
                val_ary = urls.val().split('\n');

                for (var i = 0; i < val_ary.length; i++)
                {
                    if (!validate_url(val_ary[i]))
                    {
                        continue;   
                    }

                    urls_ary[i] = val_ary[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (validate_url(urls.val()))
                {
                    single_url = urls.val();
                }
            }

            if (urls_ary.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < urls_ary.length; i++)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        // do AJAX here.                            
                    }); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    // do AJAX here.                                
                });     
            }
        }
    });

    function validate_url(url)
    {
        if(/^([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(url)){
          return true;
        }   

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: That has been answered here (using Regex) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8667222/448865

Comment: _"This would be quite easy to solve of the text area accepted one URL only"_ - So use the string `.split()` method to separate the entered values on line breaks and then use a loop to validate each of the items in the resulting array one at a time. Or if you were validating with a regex just extend the pattern to allow repeats.

Comment: @nnnnnn Brilliant! I didn't know Javascript had a similar function/method equivalent to PHP's `explode()`!

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods) are some other string methods you might not be aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) makes use of a method such as this:

```
var anyURL = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
if(/^([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(anyURL))     {
  /* the URL is valid */
} else {
  /* the URL is invalid)
}
```

You can use that code directly or use the [validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) itself.

Please note: it may be that the plugin has evolved and the actual code is different now. Nonetheless, the above should help you.

Comment: Thank you! I've used the provided `if` statement.